# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout

[DOCUMENTAÇÃO OFICIAL DO ANDROID SOBRE TOOLBAR](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html)

Eu estou seguindo a documentação oficial do Android, e mesmo assim estou tendo problemas, pois gerou esse erro.

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in
>   com.resource.actionbar:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #5
>   in com.resource.actionbar:layout/toolbar: Error inflating class
>   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5 in com.resource.actionbar:layout/toolbar: Error inflating class
>   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)

Eu seguir todas recomendações
Essa é minha activity.

```
package com.resource.actionbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setActionBar(myToolbar);
    }
}
```

Já tentei trocar este **android.widget.Toolbar** por este **androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar** e mesmo assim não funcionou! preciso de ajuda!

Comment: Teria como você postar também o layout XML dessa activity, pela sua StackTracer acredito que o problema esteja lá, mais preciso confirmar pra ter certeza.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era no meu arquivo XML, eu peguei esse modelo no GitHub, e funcionou!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


       <Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
           android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
           android:elevation="4dp"
           android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar"
           android:popupTheme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light"
           tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```